# Google Tag Manager and AMP

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp

I am setting up AMP for my news site. Does anyone know if there is Google Tag Manager Support? I know you can use Google Analytics. I wonder if I use GA tracking code on all /amp/ pages it will track double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I originally tried adding the GTM using [Glue for Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/glue-for-yoast-seo-amp/) and it did track the pages. However, that resulted in 2 AMP validation errors:

[image: AMP Google Tag Manager validation errors]

The proper way of implementing the tag as of right now is via amp-pixel or amp-analytics. I used amp-analytics tag myself. First you would add this in the head:

```
  <script async custom-element="amp-analytics"
    src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

And then the tracking code goes in the body inside this tag using JSON:

```
 <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1"></amp-analytics>
```

Full details can be found here:

[Adding Analytics to your AMP pages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/)

Answer (score 2):

Google Tag Manager now added AMP support.
All you need is to

1. create a GTM container of type "AMP"
2. Include the following code in `<head>`

   ```
    <!-- AMP Analytics --><script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
   ```
3. Include the following code into `<body>`

   ```
   <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
   <amp-analytics config="https://www.googletagmanager.com/amp.json?id=GTM-XXXXXX&gtm.url=SOURCE_URL" data-credentials="include"></amp-analytics>
   ```

Find some more info about that on Simo Ahava's blog
http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/accelerated-mobile-pages-via-google-tag-manager

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error "Fetch API cannot load https://www.googletagmanager.com/amp.json?id=GTM-54HXDWD&gtm.url=http%3A%2F…ost%3A8080%2Fde-de%2Famp&__amp_source_origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled..

Answer (score 2):

Not just there is a Tag Manager Support but that's the primary supported way for analytics for a while now. The older way posted by Andrea Rapanaro in 2016 used GA property identifiers. The current one is described by https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics - also cited by dasickle.

Here's my take:

1. In the HTML document header section: `<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
2. In my `_config.yml`: `gtag: "GTM-NPS2Q4K"` (https://gitlab.com/MrCsabaToth/mrcsabatoth.gitlab.io/-/blob/master/_config.yml#L36). This is Jekyll, if you use other static site generator / SSG / framework you'd need to use the particular framework's configuration method.
3. The actual configuration (the G tag is interpolated by Jekyll, you can simply replace it by yourself or use your preferred SSG's way of interpolation):

```
    <amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
      <script type="application/json">
        {
          "vars" : {
            "gtag_id": "{{ site.ga }}",
            "config" : {
              "{{ site.ga }}": { "groups": "default" }
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
    </amp-analytics>
```

This even works with GDPR if you add `data-block-on-consent` to the `amp-analytics` HTML element like in https://gitlab.com/MrCsabaToth/mrcsabatoth.gitlab.io/-/blob/master/_layouts/default.html#L10

This actually might be weird for those who only have Google Analytics now and no Google Tag Manager configuration. Make sure you establish a default Workspace in Google Tag Manager, otherwise your gtag won't work. I learned that the hard way.